# Trouble deploying Spring 4 WAR to Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

I'm having trouble deploying the WAR to a Weblogic 12c server.

> nested exception is javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError:
>   Provider for class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be created

```
<Feb 8, 2017 2:47:02 PM EST> <Warning> <org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext> <BEA-000000> <Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcUriComponentsContributor' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.method.support.CompositeUriComponentsContributor]: Factory method 'mvcUriComponentsContributor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be created>
<Feb 8, 2017 2:47:02 PM EST> <Error> <org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader> <BEA-000000> <Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcUriComponentsContributor' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.method.support.CompositeUriComponentsContributor]: Factory method 'mvcUriComponentsContributor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be created
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:725)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:192)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1910)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3063)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1830)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:875)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:82)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:753)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:263)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:53)
       at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:601)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:343)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:895)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1422)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:454)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.method.support.CompositeUriComponentsContributor]: Factory method 'mvcUriComponentsContributor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcValidator' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be created
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
```

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.12'        

    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.2'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'cn.guoyukun.jdbc', name: 'oracle-ojdbc6', version: '11.2.0.3.0'

    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.15'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.10'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-xml', version: '2.8.6' 

    compile (group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '4.3.5.RELEASE') {
        exclude group: 'javax.xml.stream', module: 'stax-api'
    } 
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.5.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.5.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.5.0'

    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:4.2.5.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-yarn-common', version: '2.6.0-cdh5.7.0'
}
```

The kicker is that **this deploys fine in a local instance of Weblogic 12c**. All other applications on the server are using Spring 3 so that leads me to believe its a change from Spring 3 to 4. Any suggestions for what settings to check or libraries to include would be very helpful.

Comment: Check if you have any stax-api conflicts while running on the server

Comment: What is a good way to check for conflicts with various libraries?